# Chained operator overloading for path propagation

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I want to implement in python a simple model for optical propagation. The rule is that if I chain three elements *m0 -> m1-> m2* what I would get as system is:

- tau = tau0 * tau1 * tau2
- B = B2 + B1*tau2 + B0*tau2*tau1

(tau is transmission, B is background).

I wanted to implement overloading the `__gt__` operator such that I can declare:

```
m0 = Mirror(0.9, 10)
m1 = Mirror(0.8, 11)
m2 = Mirror(0.7, 12)
x = m0 > m1 > m2
```

So far I wrote this:

```
class OpticalElement:
    def __init__(self, trans, background):
        self.trans = trans
        self.background = background

class Mirror(OpticalElement):       
    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Mirror):
            tau = self.trans * other.trans
            bkg = other.background + other.trans * self.background
            return Mirror(tau, bkg)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
```

However this code seems only to get the transmission and background of the rightmost elements:

```
x = m0 > m1 > m2
x.trans
```

Returns 0.56, while I am expecting 0.504.
Background behaves the same, I am getting 19.7 instead of 25.3 (first element ignored).

**Do you guys have any idea on how to implement several chained elements using the operator overloading?** (putting parenthesis works, but I wanted to have cleaner code).

Thanks!

Andreu

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it would be trivial if you called it with a function `def chain(*args: [Mirror]) -> Mirror` as opposed to chaining with an operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m0 > m1 > m2` is equivalent to `(m0 > m1) and (m1 > m2)`.

As `m0 > m1` will be considered `True`, `and` will test `m1 > m2` and return its value, which is the 0.56 you get.

You could use the multiplication operator, which will work as expected:

```
class OpticalElement:
    def __init__(self, trans, background):
        self.trans = trans
        self.background = background

class Mirror(OpticalElement):       
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Mirror):
            tau = self.trans * other.trans
            bkg = other.background + other.trans * self.background
            return Mirror(tau, bkg)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

m0 = Mirror(0.9, 10)
m1 = Mirror(0.8, 11)
m2 = Mirror(0.7, 12)
x = m0 *m1 * m2
print(x.trans)
#0.504
```

Comment: Probably the right shift operator, `>>` ([`__rshift__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rshift__)), would be the closest to the intended syntax: `x = m0 >> m1 >> m2`.

Comment: Actually the solution from @jdehesa is the most elegant one and closest to what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way chained comparisons work is that `m0 > m1 > m2` is evaluated as `(m0 > m1) and (m1 > m2)`, which results in `m1 > m2`, as `x and y`returns `y` if `x` is truish.
So this is the reason why your code seems only to get the rightmost comparison.

Instead, you can do
`x = (m0 > m1) > m2`.
which evaluates both `>` operators in the given order.
This results in

```
x = (m0 > m1) > m2
print(x.trans) # 0.504
```

Comment: OP said `putting parenthesis works, but I wanted to have cleaner code` though

Comment: Exactly, @Arne, I wanted to keep that syntax without parenthesis. Thanks.